# rewrite map (prg:) never finishes

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite

using Apache and a prg type rewrite map.   My map looks like:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
$| = 1; # Turn off buffering 
while (<STDIN>) {
    print "someothersite.com";
}
```

the rewrite rule declared in httpd.conf is:

```
RewriteMap app_map prg:/file/path/test.pl
RewriteRule  (\/[\w]+)(\/[^\#\s]+)?$ http://${app_map:$1}$2 [P,L]
```

And the log files show:

```
init rewrite engine with requested uri /a/testlink.html
applying pattern '(\/[\w]+)(\/[^\#\s]+)?$' to uri '/a/testlink.html'
```

It appears like test.pl is never giving control back to apache, when the map is successfully found I expect to see this output in the log file:

```
map lookup OK: map=app_map key=/a -> val=someothersite.com
```

Why is my map not returning control back to apache?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it working with the following:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
#
##   disable buffered I/O which would lead
##   to deadloops for the Apache server
$| = 1;
#
##   read URLs one per line from stdin
while (<>) {
    my $line = $_;
    if ($line eq "input_from_apache\n"){
        print "my_desired_output\n";    
    }   
    else{
        print "\n";
    }
}
```

As best I can tell, the newline characters are what I was missing.  For anyone trying to debug a RewriteMap script I suggest:

1. Make sure you have:

   `RewriteEngine On`

   `RewriteLog /var/log/httpd/rewrite.log`

   `RewriteLogLevel 9`

   in your httpd.conf so you can see what mod_rewrite is doing
2. Write your script, and then start it (i.e. `./my_script.pl`) and type in some inputs to make sure you're getting what you expect.  That's how I realized that I needed the `\n`'s

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried having your Perl script return the right format?  It expects a key/value pair, i.e.:

```
someval someothersite.com
```

That may correct your issues.  If not, you can try using a txt file to simulate what your Perl script returns, to verify that the `RewriteMap` is working at all.

Comment: If the map were a text file, I could see your point.  But a prg type map should receive an input, and respond with an output